# Limit SSH traffic?

Tags: ssh, bandwidth, traffic

I would like to be able to limit SSH bandwidth on my server.  I.e. each sshd process should be limited to 200Kb/s or something like that.

scp has this functionality, but ssh, being more designed for responsive interactive use, doesn't seem to have this option.  I however, would like to combine the -D (SOCKS proxy) functionality with some ability to somehow limit traffic.

Are there any options for this at all?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the SSH server, or is it Ok to do it on a firewall between the two machines?

Comment: I'd really rather do this on the server, since I don't have access to the firewall.

Comment: If you are happy doing this on the client, try the command line utility 'drizzle'.

Comment: While the drizzle command looks useful, I ultimately can't trust users to run it.

Looks like I'm stuck looking at something a bit more complicated than I hoped for :P.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if trusting users is part of the equation, but `trickle` is very handy for limiting the speed of a given command. When I upload packages from home, the WoW-addict roommates notice when I forget something like that, since it pretty much dominates the pipe.

Comment: Trickle can run as a daemon to and manage total bandwidth for multiple commands on the same machine. Handy when you want to set off a bunch of otherwise independent transfer operations at the same time but want them to use no more than a set data rate in total.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that'll help me with sshd -- it forks off new sshds as new connections come in.  I might be stuck with some firewall level solution, which will be a bit more tricky to implement.

Comment: wtf why is this the top answer? `trickle` doesn't work with any process that forks. That includes sshd!

Answer (score 2):

```
scp -l 8192 file.txt user_name@111.111.1.11:/tmp
//8192  = 8192 KB per second
```

I know this thread is quite old, but hope this will help someone.

Comment: It's annoying that two people have downvoted your answer without at least commenting.  I'm presuming it's because `scp` is a rather specific use case of ssh.
I've tested `scp -l` and it works, although note that it's kilobits (kb) per second, and not kilobytes (kB).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

A common one is to implement QoS on Port 22 on a firewall/router between the server and the clients.

If they are on the same local network (i.e. no routers or firewalls between them), I believe you can use IPTables to limit bandwidth to port 22... [Have a look here](http://www.geocities.com/youssef116/writing/ratelim.html) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: You need to be careful using iptables' rate limiter with a service like ssh, because "It is important to observe that rate limiting is conceptually different from bandwidth throttling/limiting; a bandwidth-throttled connection will queue packets and limit the rate at which they are transmitted/received. Rate limiting will not do this; when you use rate limiting on, for example, incoming TCP connection attempts to your identd, and connections exceeding the specified limit will be denied; *there is no queueing of packets*."

Comment: Hmmm goood point

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth looking into implementing HTB traffic shaping using tc. My solution to a simular problem was to use the htb.init script found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/htbinit/

I set it up based on limiting traffic from port 22, but you can also use iptables to mark/mangle the packets which are then processed based on the mark.

Comment: +1 for the only `tc` related answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [iprelay](http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/):

```
User-space bandwidth shaping TCP proxy daemon
iprelay can shape the TCP traffic forwarded through it to a specified
bandwidth and allow this bandwidth to be changed on-the-fly. Multiple
data streams to different sockets may be shaped to the same total
bandwidth, much like a traffic shaping router would. However, this
application runs in user space, and works by acting as a TCP proxy.
```